# First project with LPC1769

Tags: arm, cortex-m3, lpcxpresso

I would buy an LPCXpresso LPC1769. I need a TCP/IP connection and an SD card reader for my project, and I can not understand if LPC1769 is ready for this (like Arduino Ethernet shield) or I need to buy and solder other components.

Thanks.

Comment: This should be in the manual.

Comment: I think this is what happens when people brought up on the Arduino try to 'graduate'.

Comment: @AngryEE: funny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a similar LPC1768 board with everything you need on it: (Ebay storefront link) [ARM NXP LPC1768 Development Board J-link Jlink On-board](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ARM-NXP-LPC1768-Development-Board-J-link-Jlink-On-board-/200508877885?pt=BI_Electrical_Equipment_Tools&hash=item2eaf42ac3d).

Answer (score 2):

The baseboard is not needed. I'm doing a project with one of these now with Ethernet and SD. You can solder wires from your connectors straight to the LPCXpresso board.

But if you have some extra cash to spend I would recommend that you get a baseboard. There are many different ones but most of them are basically the same.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at this page: http://www.lpctools.com/lpc1768.lpcxpresso.aspx quickly shows that the lpcxpresso board does NOT have the connectors you are looking for.  That particular board would need to be soldered to a baseboard of some kind that has an ethernet jack with magnetics, and an SD card socket.  A quick google search revealed this: http://www.embeddedartists.com/products/lpcxpresso/xpr_base.php A baseboard that accepts the LPC1769 lpcxpresso board and has all of the breakouts you say you need.

I would strongly recommend doing a bit more research before asking questions here.  It took me all of 2 minutes to find this information via Google.